# Cmake : LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS equivalent in CMake

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I am working on an android native app currently using `Android.mk` for build. We are moving build system to `CMake`.
I have following lines in `Android.mk` :

```
LOCAL_MODULE := midso
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libC
```

What are `CMake` equivalents of `LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS` and `LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES` ?

Comment: `target_link_libraries(mytarget PUBLIC log)` ?

Comment: what will be syntax for LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries